# How to key in the input field as Chips

Tags: html, angular, input, angular-material

I need help with the coding on changing the current type of input field. The input field is called "types", where user types in an input.  I need to change the current type of input field to a "Chips" input field where the user will type in the input and it will show as Chips when press Enter

```
    <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex="30" class="mr-8">
      <div class="mb-8" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start start">
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex>
          <mat-label>Types</mat-label>
          <input name="type" formControlName="type" placeholder="Types" matInput>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
```

The results should be when a user enters a input in the field, it will come out and shown as chips

Comment: I am a bit confused.. By chips, are you referring to something like this: https://material.angular.io/components/chips?

Comment: yes exactly, chips like that. so when a user inputs a text it will saved as a chip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a trick/hack to do. Hide and show either the input or the chip based if the enter key is pressed. I made an example with ngModel, you can adapt it to reactive forms:

**HTML**

```
<mat-chip *ngIf="finished">
    {{myInput}}
</mat-chip>
<input placeholder="Type here the new chip" [(ngModel)]="myInput" matInput *ngIf="!finished" (keydown.enter)="finished=true">
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lb6kzx)

Comment: do you know how i can add more than 1 chips to the input? for example, l'd like to add maybe 3 or 4 inputs and they all be turned out as chips when i click enter.

Comment: It works Vega thank you, but um id like to have only 1 input area where you can add multiple chips to it. Also can you help me add delete function to the chips as well? for example, the user keys in a input, it saves as chips and user can click an "x" at the chip to delete it.

Comment: This is what of my code so far:

          <ng-container *ngFor="let type of types; let i = index">
          <mat-chip *ngIf="finished[i]" [selectable]="selectable" [removable]="removable" (removed)="remove(type)">
            {{type.name}}
          <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
          </mat-chip>
        <input name="type" formControlName="type" placeholder="Types" [(ngModel)]="type.name" *ngIf="!finished[i]" (blur)="finished[i]=true" (keydown.enter)="finished[i]=true" matInput>
        </ng-container>
        </mat-form-field>
        </div>

Comment: The Angular Material page has an example for exactly what you are looking for, one input and multiple chips. Have you seen it? Here is a demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g1gmny

Comment: yeah ive seen it but i dont know how to implement it haha, thanks anyway!

Comment: As I read your comment, it seems to be exactly what my last link refers to. Could you explain what is the diiference with your need?

Comment: its just that i have to implement this changes to a project i'm currently working on, i got it already, its okay thanks vega!